# Trying to make a screen saver from a jframe, cant switch images

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, screensaver

I'm trying to make a screesaver frame in java.swing using the NetBeans GUI builder. The images won't display when i set an infinte loop that cycles between them. The images are set to display on a jLabel through setIcon. Here's the code below:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class AdFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form FifthFrame
     */
    public AdFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jPanel1.setOpaque(false);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/btc_gui/newpackage/btc-zg.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AdFrame ff1 = new AdFrame();
                ff1.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                ff1.setVisible(true);
                int index = 0;
                String[] filearray = new String[2];
                filearray[0] = "/btc_gui/newpackage/btc-zg.jpg";
                filearray[1] = "/btc_gui/newpackage/pic2.jpeg";
                while (true){
                    ff1.jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filearray[index])));
                    ff1.jLabel1.repaint();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(AdFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    index++;
                    if (index >= filearray.length) index = 0;
                }
            }

        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Do you know what [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) means?

Comment: It is the reason why youre code does not work

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please elaborate?

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

You have an infinite loop and you tell the EDT Thread to sleep. Since the EDIT is responsible for painting the GUI the painting can never be done because the EDT is constantly sleeping.

Don't use an infinite loop and don't use Thread.sleep().

Instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the screen saver.